# Can vim automatically correct a spelling mistake if the word doesn't end in a space?

Tags: abbreviations

I use vim for writing code and often accidentally type this:

`funciton() {}`

instead of

`function() {}`

It's irritating and I know vim supports **iabbrev** for this purpose.  But it doesn't work in this case since there is not a space after the word *function*.  Blame our coding standards I guess.  But is there a way either out-of-the-box or through a plugin to automatically correct such a thing?

Comment: It is strange, because `iabbr funciton function` works fine here when typing `funciton(` -- it doesn't requires any spaces.

Comment: @mMontu it didn't work for me. Edit - worked with plugins/vimrc disabled.

Comment: @Al.G. maybe some plugin/configuration? Because it worked fine here even in vanilla vim. Try starting vim with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE`, them try the contents of my previous comment.

Comment: In my case it's definitely a plugin, but it'd be hard to tell of 20 which one is causing it. Do you know about some quick way of disabling them one by one? (except `set rtp-=~/.vim/pluginname`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the simple abbreviation `iabbr funciton function`  works on my setup and in vanilla vim, without any need of type space -- it is triggered by the `(`.

Your problem is being caused by some specific configuration/plugin; thus you should follow the procedure described on [Vim-FAQ  2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5):

> 2.5. I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a
>        problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?
>
> First, you need to find out, whether the error is in the actual
>   runtime files or any plugin that is distributed with Vim or whether it
>   is a simple side effect of any configuration option from your .vimrc
>   or .gvimrc. So first, start vim like this:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> this starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.
>
> If the error does not occur when starting Vim this way, then the
>   problem is either related to some plugin of yours or some setting in
>   one of your local setup files. You need to find out, what triggers the
>   error, you try starting Vim this way:
>
> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N
> ```
>
> If the error occurs, the problem is your .viminfo file. Simply delete
>   the viminfo file then. If the error does not occur, try:
>
> ```
> vim -u ~/.vimrc --noplugin -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This will simply use your .vimrc as configuration file, but not load
>   any plugins. If the error occurs this time, the error is possibly
>   caused by some configuration option inside your .vimrc file. Depending
>   on the length of your vimrc file, it can be quite hard to trace the
>   origin within that file.
>
> The best way is to add :finish command in the middle of your .vimrc.
>   Then restart again using the same command line. If the error still
>   occurs, the bug must be caused because of a setting in the first half
>   of your .vimrc. If it doesn't happen, the problematic setting must be
>   in the second half of your .vimrc. So move the :finish command to the
>   middle of that half, of which you know that triggers the error and
>   move your way along, until you find the problematic option. If your
>   .vimrc is 350 lines long, you need at a maximum 9 tries to find the
>   offending line (in practise, this can often be further reduced, since
>   often lines depend on each other).
>
> If the problem does not occur, when only loading your .vimrc file, the
>   error must be caused by a plugin or another runtime file (indent
>   autoload or syntax script). Check the output of the :scriptnames
>   command to see what files have been loaded and for each one try to
>   disable each one by one and see which one triggers the bug. Often
>   files that are loaded by vim, have a simple configuration variable to
>   disable them, but you need to check inside each file separately.

Comment: For me, the culprit was vim-smartinput, which completes parentheses, brackets, etc.  Not surprising I guess, but it leaves me without a way to do one thing or the other.  Thanks for the help.  It didn't occur to me that it could be a plugin until you mentioned it.

Comment: @user37078 glad you figured it out.